# How to create hypelink within a Word document without using bookmarks

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

I'm creating a glossary of terms which often include terms the reader may not be familiar with, so I hyperlink to new terms. This glossary keeps growing, so when using bookmarks for hyperlink locations it doesn't work.  When I insert a new term (alphabetically), the new term now occupies the bookmark location of the previous term and the hyperlink to take you there is no longer effective.

Comment: You can use bookmarks if when you add new definitions, you go to the END of the preceding definition and press return to add the new blank paragraph for your new definition.  That way your bookmarks won't be incorrect as the existing bookmark will move down with its associated text correctly.  (If you do it the other way of going to the start of the existing bookmarked definition where you want to insert the new definition above and press return, that is when your bookmarks will go awry).

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in this case is

1. First select the text you want to hyperlink
2. Right-Click on the selected text
3. Click 'Hyperlink'
4. Select what type you want it to hyperlink to and then
5. Type the URL

Comment: Display the paragraph marks while you're editing so you can see what you're doing when you add a new definition.  When you create a new definition, select the entire word (or first letter if you want), then create ("insert") the bookmark.  That ensures the bookmark is applied to the actual word, not the paragraph mark.